# EC2のセキュリティグループ設定時にIPアドレスの末尾に付加する/24等の意味

Tags: amazon-ec2

EC2のセキュリティグループ設定時にIPアドレスの末尾に付加する/24等の意味を教えてください

SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0 <- この/0の意味が分かりません
SSH TCP 22 113.52.16.113/32 <- この/32の意味が分かりません

ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

設定するのは正確には「IPアドレス」ではなく[CIDR; Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)と呼ばれる「IPアドレス範囲」です。

0.0.0.0/0 は 0.0.0.0～255.255.255.255 つまりIPv4全体を表し、
113.52.16.113/32 は 113.52.16.113～113.52.16.113 つまり113.52.16.113のみを表します。